# Using grid_propagate(False) in tkinter

Tags: python, methods, tkinter, grid

I am creating a `Frame` that uses the grid manager. And I have a `Label` widgets in it. I want the label widget to fill to the frame that it is in. But instead the frame resizes itself to the label widget. I have tried using the method `grid_propagate(False)`. But it does not seem to be working. I don't know if it is just the way that I am using it or something else.

```
def fields(self):
    frame_row = 0
    frame_column = 0
    row_count = 0
    color = "red"
    
    for i in range(50):
        self.bfr2.columnconfigure(frame_column, pad=10)
        self.bfr2.rowconfigure(frame_row, pad=10)
        
        self.frame = Frame(self.bfr2, bg="grey", width=229, height=120)
        self.frame.grid(row=frame_row, column=frame_column)
        self.frame.grid_propagate(False) #This is where it should prevent the Frame from re sizing but it does not.

        self.sum = Label(self.frame, bg="green", text="This is a summary of a note")
        self.sum.pack(side=TOP, fill=BOTH)
        
        frame_column = frame_column + 1
        row_count = row_count + 1

        if row_count == 2:
            frame_row = frame_row + 1
            frame_column = 0
            row_count = 0

            if color == "red":
                color = "green"
            else:
                color = "red"

        if color == "red":
            color = "green"
        else:
            color = "red"
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are calling `grid_propagate` but then using `pack()` to put widgets in it. Try doing

```
self.frame.pack_propagate(False)
```